# can I print something inside of the round brackets in while loop with the condition?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I was playing with this code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class plus
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            System.out.print("Youe Value: ");
            long tobe = scan.nextLong();

            int total = 0;

            String parsed = String.valueOf(tobe);

            for(int i = 0; i < parsed.length(); i++) {
                total += Character.getNumericValue(parsed.charAt(i));
            }

            System.out.println("Your Result: "+ total);
        }
        while(scan.hasNextLong());
    }
}
```

The output should prompt for a number then process it and print as Result.

and then again with another input if that's a `integer(long)`

but the condition in  `while` loop `scan.hasnextLong` takes input itself and process it and the output is like this-

**Your Value: Your Result: n**

but the expected output is like this-

**Your Value: m**

**Your Result: n**

as like the first time. ***tobe*** does not seems taking input after first time. its just using what give in loop condition to check if thats a `integer`. more clearly the program prompt before printing **Your Value:**  and use this value in **tobe**.

So i wanted to print inside of `while` loop condion

somewhere in this line with condition inside the round brackets

```
while(scan.hasNextLong())
```

so it print and prompt like I wanted;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code so the scanner gets a `String` input.
The `while` condition then checks if it contains only numbers. It does that by calling `.matches()` on the input, which tries to match the input string with the Regular Expression `\d+`. This expression matches a series of one or more digits. `\d` is for a digit, `+` is a quantifier. You can learn about and play with Regular Expressions on sites like [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    System.out.print("Your Value: ");

    while ((input = scan.nextLine()).matches("\\d+")){

        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            total += Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Your Result: "+ total);
        System.out.println("\nYour Value: ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nTHE END.");
    scan.close();
```

Comment: so .matches("\\d+") checks if the string contain just digits? if so I understood. 
but I also wanted to printout inaide of condition. and will u also plz explain how the matches method works? clearly. why \\d+ etc etc.

Comment: @Rabin I added an explanation of the `.matches()` method. Unfortunately I don't understand why you want to print something inside of the condition. I still hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're triyng to print a value before initializing it. If you use `print` instead of `println` the next output will be on the same line.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            do{

                long tobe = scan.nextLong();
                System.out.println("Your Value: " + tobe);

                int total = 0;

                String parsed = String.valueOf(tobe);

                for(int i = 0; i < parsed.length(); i++) {
                    total += Character.getNumericValue(parsed.charAt(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Your Result: "+ total);
            }
            while(scan.hasNextLong());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while(scan.hasNextLong());` with `while(scan.hasNextLine());`